# cURL error [0]: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8545: Connection refused

Tags: php, ethereum, erc20

I am using laravel package(furqansiddiqui/erc20-php) for erc20 token transfer, But i am getting error when execute the code

```
$geth = new EthereumRPC('127.0.0.1', 8545);

    $erc20 = new ERC20($geth);
    $token = $erc20->token("0x05f4a42e251f2d52b8ed15e9fedaacfcef1fad27");
    var_dump($token->name()); // string(7) "Zilliqa"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run geth by `--rpc` parameter

```
geth --rpc
```

As easier way to connect to Ethereum network, you can use https://infura.io

Infura support mainnet and testnets (rinkeby, ropsten, kovan, goerli), thats good for development.